# Angular... Name of radio buttons in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of items, that contain a field with a value from a fixed list.
I want to show these as radio buttons in a form.

I simplified the code a bit, in a fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/my4k7Lo8/

The HTML:

```
<div ng-app='MyApp'>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <form>
            <div ng-form ng-repeat="item in list" name="itemForm">
                <div style="border: 1px solid black">
                     <h4>Item {{$index}}</h4>

                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="color" ng-model="item.color" value="red" required />red</label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="color" ng-model="item.color" value="blue" required />blue</label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="color" ng-model="item.color" value="green" required />green</label>
                    <p ng-show="itemForm.color.$error.required">
                        Must choose a color
                    </p>
                    <p>Actual color is {{item.color}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The JS:

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
    .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.list = [{
        // no color set yet
    }, {
        color: "green"
    }, {
        color: "red"
    }];
}]);
```

Only one radio button is selected at all times, because of the shared names between all the radio buttons. I do want an error message though when no value is selected, and I want to prevent the user from clicking a submit button.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 7):

You need to create different names for each group of radio buttons. The way you could do this within `ng-repeat` is by using `$index`:

```
<div ng-form ng-repeat="item in list" name="itemForm">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="color{{$index}}" 
             ng-model="item.color" value="red" required />red</label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="color{{$index}}" 
             ng-model="item.color" value="blue" required />blue</label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="color{{$index}}" 
             ng-model="item.color" value="green" required />green</label>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use $index inside the ng-repeat.
Eg:   `<input type="radio" name="color{{$index}}"/>`

This will help you.